# PositionIndex of isomorphic value

Tags: list-manipulation

The following example is a simplified version of a problem I am working on:

```
equivalent[x_, y_] := Mod[x, 7] == Mod[y, 7]
```

Given a list, say {3, 7, 5} and an integer 21. I need to determine the position of 21 in the list. If I use PositionIndex (which is what I want to use) then the result is

```
Missing["KeyAbsent", 21]
```

I need the result to be {2}, i.e. the position of 7 in the list (where 7 is identified with 21 through the equivalence relation).

Is there a way to define PositionIndex up to isomorphism? I.e. so that it returns positions of elements A that are equivalent to list elements B in the list by returning the position of B (for the element A)?

ETA: the result should not depend on the actual value of 7.

So in case the list is {3,14,5} and the element is 21, the result should still be {2}. In the application I cannot assume anything about the integers contained in the list (or the element of which the position in the list needs to be determined). The position should be {2} in case the given element is equivalent to the list element in second position.

Comment: `equivalent[x_, y_] := Mod[x - y, 7] == 0;
equivclass[x_] := Mod[x, 7, 1];
Position[{3, 7, 5}, equivclass[21]]`

Comment: If I understood correctly: Mod[x,7,1] plays on the fact that we know 7 is the first representative. Can it be done so it works for any representative? For instance {3, 21, 5} for the element 14 should yield {2} as well, i.e. it should work for any two equivalent elements (where we cannot assume we know anything specific about the list elements)

Comment: Like this? `Position[equivclass/@{3, 21, 5}, equivclass[21]]`

Comment: Oh I see! Very cool. Would that blow up matters computation wise? Does not seem to. Much appreciated! I assume that it works for associations too? I will test it on PositionIndex. Yes works perfect, thanks!

Comment: So Mod[x,7] should suffice now as definition of equivclass[x_]. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you wanted to use `PositionIndex`, and you show a sample result of `Missing["KeyAbsent", 21]`, so I'm assuming that you're wanting to turn the list into an association that can be queried with a given target key but matching based on an equivalence using `Mod` for some other integer. Let's say our target modulus is 7 and our target key is 21. We could proceed like this:

```
posIdx = PositionIndex[{3, 7, 5, 14}];
KeySelect[posIdx, Divisible[21 - #, 7] &]
```

`<|7 -> {2}, 14 -> {4}|>`

This maintains the original values, but if that's not useful, then just take the values:

```
Values[KeySelect[posIdx, Divisible[21 - #, 7] &]]
```

`{{2}, {4}}`

You could also have applied the `Mod` to the list before applying `PositionIndex`. In either case, we would need to be careful about repeated values. But if you don't actually need to use `PositionIndex`, then we can get that same result more directly:

```
Position[{3, 7, 5, 14}, _?(Divisible[21 - #, 7] &)]
```

Either of these can easily be bundled into a function. I'm confused by why you need `PositionIndex`, so I'll demonstrate with the second strategy since it's simpler.

```
PositionByEquivalence[mod_, target_, list_] := Position[list, _?(Divisible[target - #, mod] &)]
```

With all the arguments explicit like this, now you can use it with any modulus and any target value.

```
PositionByEquivalence[7, 21, {3, 7, 5, 14}]
```

`{{2}, {4}}`

```
PositionByEquivalence[10, 15, {3, 7, 5, 14}]
```

`{{3}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
equivalent[x_, y_] := Mod[x, 7] == Mod[y, 7]

Position[{3,7,5},x_/;equivalent[x,21],1]

(*  {{2}}  *)
```